# Does LinkedList start searching from the end if you want element that is nearly its tail?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

I am interested how LinkedList is searching data when I want to get it. 
For example: 
We have a LinkedList with 1000 elements in it. And I want to take element by index 950 so I write "`list.get (950)`". Will java starts to look for that element from the beginning? Or it has a pointer to the last element too? 
I have written small programm to test it. But it works incorrectly(showing bigest time for the first get, whatever it is.

```
long time;
time = System.nanoTime();
list.get(1);
time = System.nanoTime() - time;
System.out.println("For element at the beginning " + time);
time = System.nanoTime();
list.get(999);
time = System.nanoTime() - time;
System.out.println("For element at the end " + time);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java) for `LinkedList` it does have a pointer to the last `Node`:

```
 /**
  * Pointer to last node.
  * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
  *            (last.next == null && last.item != null)
  */
transient Node<E> last;
```

Which is used in with one of the internal methods called with `get`:

```
Node<E> node(int index) {
    // assert isElementIndex(index);

    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        Node<E> x = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            x = x.next;
        return x;
    } else {
        Node<E> x = last;
        for (int i = size - 1; i > index; i--)
            x = x.prev;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't mean it starts from the tail when doing a `get` (although it does).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! And examples! It helps!

Answer (score 2):

1. Can you please show the observed timings, I suspect they are so close that you cannot make any conclusions based on them!?
2. See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) to write proper benchmarks
3. You can simply inspect the source code of linkedlist to see how it "searches".
4. `LinkedList` *does* in fact have a `first` and `last` reference and **yes**, it has logic to "search" from the back if your index is reasonable close (`if (index >= (size >> 1))`)

Comment: Timings are too different. And the first time is always bigger than second.
For example:
For element at the beginning 11605 ns
For element at the end 3755 ns
and when I change the order of calls:
For element at the end 11605
For element at the beginning 2048
It makes no sense for me.
Can you please explain why so?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it starts from the back if the element is over half way along:

```
Node<E> node(int index) {
    // assert isElementIndex(index);

    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        Node<E> x = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            x = x.next;
        return x;
    } else {
        Node<E> x = last;
        for (int i = size - 1; i > index; i--)
            x = x.prev;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers.

Your test is correct. Check `LinkedList#node` source in other answers. Index 999 is the last one in your list, so `node()` method returns last element immediately. Index 1 is the second in the list (first is 0), so when you call `get(1)` there is additional for loop iteration to get element next after the first one.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. I have changed it to get(0) but it still gets strange results.Timings are too different. And the first time is always bigger than second. For example: For element at the beginning 11605 ns For element at the end 3755 ns and when I change the order of calls: For element at the end 11605 For element at the beginning 2048 It makes no sense for me. Can you please explain why so?

Comment: It's definitely some JVM optimization. E.g. there is no need to calculate ```size >> 1``` twice for consecutive get calls if list size is not changed.

Comment: Hm maybe I understand it now. Thanks!